# Calling setTimeouts by callbacks or promises

Tags: node.js, express

I have 3 setTimeouts and I need to execute one by one (synchronous manner) by using callbacks or promises below is the my code and output.

Hi I am order 1, Hi I am order 2, Hi I am order 3.

Below is the my code:

```
             setTimeout(function() {
                  console.log('Hi I am order 1');
                    test2();
                }, 3000);

                  setTimeout(function() {
                  console.log('Hi I am order 2');
                     test3();
                }, 2000);


                  setTimeout(function() {
                  console.log('Hi I am order 3');
                }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You are calling functions like `test2()` from your `setTimeout` callbacks. Just wrap you `setTimeout`s in those functions.

For example:

```
function test2(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('Hi I am order 2');
        test3(); // <-- you'll also need a test3()
    }, 2000);
}
```

If you do that with all of them, they will call in order. If you wrap the first `setTimeout` in a function as well…say `test1()` then you can kick the whole thing off by calling that function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly - you want each function to run when the previous one ends.
A simple way would be to call each one from the last line of the preceding one.
With promises I would use http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

`Promise.each` serially runs all your functions.
Note that it expects a promise (if you don't respond with a promise - it will run all of them in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Hi I am order 1");
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hi I am order 2");
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Hi I am order 3");
        },1000)}
    ,2000)
},3000)
```